# How can I know which AWS region has the lowest latency from my location?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How can I check which Amazon region is has the lowest latency from my present location? Is there some script that pings servers on all of them several times and calculates the average latency?

Preferably a solution that also compares latency to the newly launched Frankfurt (eu-central-1) region.

Comment: Actually, yes.  http://www.cloudping.info/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a site like CloudWatch: http://www.cloudwatch.in/. It measures EC2, SimpleDB, SQS and SNS services latency from your browser.

**Edit:** CloudWatch doesn't contain the new eu-central-1 location, however I submitted a PR to add it. I will update this answer when it gets accepted.

**Edit 2:** PR has been accepted, the list on the site now contains Frankfurt.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like [cloudwatch.in](http://www.cloudwatch.in) is no longer running. @Anthony Neace's comment on the question mentioned [cloudping.info](https://www.cloudping.info/) which works as a replacement.